# Google script to copy and paste row to another tab based on Value in column L then delete Row

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Below is a screenshot of the sheet i am trying to put a script that will copy from column 1 to 15 based on data in column 11 and then paste it into sheet 2 where i am keeping a on going log and then delete the row from the original sheet. i know how to do a basic script to copy paste and delet but do not know how i would  target rows base of a colunms value would truly appreciate the help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmXvZ.png)

ive tried a query() formula and filter formula but need something that delets the row from the original sheet. i have tried going through code that others have previously provided and taylor to my scenario but have been unsucessful.

Comment: Column L is 12 do you want 12 or 11?

Comment: sorry colunm K so 11.

Comment: used the updated script but after inputting my tab names now it doesnt copy paste or delete but not errors

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q1MwUdkwb4e6gCpJ3xWOnITka7YEqCziUMkRVIFn09w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Copy and Delete

```
function copyrowswherelequalyoupick() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  let d = 0;//deleted row counter
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var o = vs.map((r, i) => {
    if (r[10] == "your pick" ) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + sr - d++);
      return r;
    }
  }).filter(e => e);//filter removes all of the undefined lines it's a truthy filter
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Output Sheet name");
  if(o.length > 0) {
    osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
  }
}
```

- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

Comment: Thank you it works for the copy and paste does not delete the row how can i add the function to delet the rows after

Comment: I can't tell from your image what row the data begins on

Comment: data begins on row 7

Comment: Okay the just set `sr=7`.

Comment: Now i get an error on line 14.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
copyrowswherelequalyoupick @ Code.gs:14

Comment: i updated sr, sheet name, your pick and output sheet name was there anything else i needed to update?

Comment: Evidently  the script did not find any meeting your requirement and I was not checking for o.length > 0

Comment: I changed sr back to 2 and deleted row 1 through 5 and it works now i will just use it  this way Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ManuelRivera are  you going to accept the answer?